# spring data neo4j 6.1.1 Repository Relationship primary_id not allowing to use UUID String where as for Node Primary_id UUID String is working

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have the following relationship entity for neo4j Graph Model using **Spring data neo4j 6.1.1** to represent relationship like Person-**BookedFor**->Movie where i can use UUID string for node repositories (Person, Movie) but not for the following relationship Entity BookedFor.

Note: since the neo4j doc describes this [neo4j doc ref](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#match-node-by-id)

```
public interface BookedForRepository extends Neo4jRepository<BookedFor, String> {}

@RelationshipProperties
public class BookedFor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)
    public String rid;

    @Property
    private Date bookedDate;

}
```

which throws error as below:

> The target class `*.entities.BookedFor` for the properties of the relationship `BookedFor` is missing a property for the generated, internal ID (`@Id @GeneratedValue Long id`) which is needed for safely updating properties

Note: If i use like following, it creates relationship with the internal id of neo4j

```
public interface BookedForRepository extends Neo4jRepository<BookedFor, Long> {}

@RelationshipProperties
public class BookedFor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Property
    private Date bookedDate;

}
```

but this will create uncertainty on data migration / data mutation as we rely on internal id of neo4j relationship entity. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

[spring data neo4j doc ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.id-handling.external-id)

Could anyone please help to proceed with this in a better way?

Also, please comment if more clarification / details required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access relationship properties directly via repositories.
Those classes are just an encapsulation for properties on relationships and are not meant to represent a "physical" relationship or more a relationship entity.
Repositories are for `@Node` annotated classes solely.

If you want to access and modify the properties of a relationship, you have to fetch the relationship defining entity.
A relationship on its own is always represented by its start and end node.

The lately introduced required `@Id` is for internal purposes only.
If you have a special need to persist an id-like property on the relationship, it would be just another property in the `@RelationshipProperties` annotated class.

Comment: okay thanks. I tried custom update query but couldn't parse the updated relationship object `@Query("match (n:PERSON {nid : $from})-[r:KNOWS]->(t:LANGUAGE {name : $to}) where ID(r) = $relationshipIdentifier set r.speak = true, r.description = 'test' return r") Optional<Object> update(@Param("from") String from, @Param("to")  String to, @Param("relationshipIdentifier")  Long relationshipIdentifier);` gives following response: {"value":{"adapted":{"start":2,"end":0,"type":"KNOWS","id":3,"properties":{"description":{"val":"test"},"speak":{}}}}} also boolean field `speak` is {} empty in response.

Comment: Thanks it works after getting the whole model. But, can't pick the precise result and make it parse in projection which may be a separate question i guess. Once again thanks a lot